# Handle different UDP message types in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, udp

I'm writing a application in NodeJs where a client sends udp messages to a server with udp. I'm trying to find out how people normally handle different message types in NodeJs but can only find tons of examples of echo servers where the kind of message is not relevant.

The only example I have found so far is https://github.com/vbo/node-webkit-mp-game-template/tree/networking_1/networking

Maybe the best way is to send the udp messages as json?

Comment: What do you mean "different message types".  If you[re trying to determine, upon receipt, what type of data the packet has in it, then you either define your packet format as a specific type and only put that type of data in it or you put a marker in the packet that indicates what type the data is or you only use some standard type such as JSON that is self describing.

Comment: Like if I have two kinds of messages that the client can send to the server. CreateAccountMessage and DeleteAccontMessage. Then the server need to handle the two messages differently.

Comment: Put a tag in the message that indicates what type of message it is.

Answer (score 1):

User Datagram Protocol (UDP) is a network protocol and mechanism for sending short messages from one host to another without any guarantee of delivery. What you put in the message is entirely up to you.

While JSON *can* be used to encode your message, it suffers from two problems: it is not secure and is self-describing.

The first problem means that bad actors can easily see the content of your message while in flight and the second implies a substantial overhead for any message above and beyond its intended purpose.

Depending on your needs, a better choice might be to define your own binary protocol specific to your purpose using a node [Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html).

Another might be to use a more compact interchange format like [thrift](https://thrift.apache.org).